# After bundling a node app into an exe, It is looking for a .node file thats path is hardcoded to the computer it was built on with node-gyp

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I have a node application that I bundle into an .exe and runs as a windows service. I include the node_modules and node.exe so the user does not need to have npm/node installed on their system. This was fine until I needed to include a .dll. I use node-gyp and a binding.gyp file to create the .node file I use in the app. It seems that node-gyp hardcodes absolute paths to the machine that built the .node file. So when the .exe tries to run on a different machine, it errors out looking for a path to my computer. Here is an example of my binding.gyp file: `{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "interface",
      "sources": [
        "src/cfcInterface/interface.cpp"
      ],
      "include_dirs": [
        "<!@(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').include\")",
        "include"
      ],
      "dependencies": [
        "<!(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').gyp\")"
      ],
      "libraries": [
        "<(module_root_dir)/lib/xxx.lib"
      ],
      "copies": [
        {
          "destination": "<(module_root_dir)/build/Release",
          "files": [
            "<(module_root_dir)/lib/xxxxxxxxx.dll",
            "<(module_root_dir)/lib/xxxxxxxx.dll",
            "<(module_root_dir)/lib/xxxxxxx.dll",
          ]
        }
      ],
      "cflags!": ["-fno-exceptions"],
      "cflags_cc!": ["-fno-exceptions"],
      "defines": ["NAPI_CPP_EXCEPTIONS"]
    }
  ]
}`

Here is the error message when trying to run the .exe: Error: Cannot open C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\node-thin-client\xxx-service\build\Release\interface.node: Error: The specified module could not be found.

This is how I am requiring the file in index.js: `const interface = require('../build/Release/interface.node');`

Everything works fine on my machine, but when installing and running the node windows service on a different machine it is still looking for the path on my computer.

Anyone know if there is a way to set relative/generic paths with node-gyp? Depending on the user to have node/npm/python/visual c++ build tools installed is not an option.

Comment: What packaging tool are you using?

Comment: I'm using Inno setup but the paths are created on npm install, so it has nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [native-ext-loader](https://github.com/smt116/node-native-ext-loader) in my webpack.config. `module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.node$/,
        loader: "native-ext-loader",
        options: {
          rewritePath: path.resolve('C:/Program Files (x86)/XXX/DeviceManager/build/Release')
        }
      }
    ]
  }`
I hard coded the installation directory the .exe is installed to.